# How can I search for a certain object in Sage?

Tags: sagemath

If I’m reading a paper and I want to try to rewrite the content in a math programming language like Sage, I’d like to search from within Sage for objects they have corresponding to a certain name, like “homological invariant”. It would be cool if objects were like Python libraries - they had internal functions and attributes, but also a natural language help doc explaining what they were.

Is there any way to search inside Sage for a certain object they might have?

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in the [Sage reference manual](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/index.html)?

Comment: I can Google and read documentation, but the idea is a function to search Sage from within the programming language.

Answer (score 2):

The functions `search_src`, `search_def`,
`search_doc`, `browse_sage_doc` might help.

Getting the Sage sources and using `git grep`
is another way one can explore the code base.

Examples of using Sage functions:

```
sage: search_def('homological')
sage: search_def('invariant')
sage: search_doc('homological')
sage: search_src('homological')
sage: browse_sage_doc(j_invariant_qexp)
```

Examples of using `git grep` (in a terminal,
from the Sage root directory):

```
$ git grep 'homological'
$ git grep 'homological' src/sage/schemes
```

(the first one searches everywhere,
the second one only in `src/sage/schemes`).